# ASP.Net, VB: Clearing fields on the webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reset, requiredfieldvalidator, rangevalidator

I am developing a website using ASP.Net and VB.

On one of the pages, there are certain fields (`TextBox`es and a `DropDownList`).
User is supposed to fill out those fields and click 'Submit' button. Also, there is a button 'Clear Values', which if clicked by user should clear the fields on the webpage.

The code I have written for clearing the fields was:

```
txtBox1.Text =  String.Empty
```

for all the `TextBox`es. But, that didn't work, as I have used few validators like `RequiredFieldValidator`, `RangeValidator`, `RegularExpressionValidator` etc. to validate the fields. So, when the user fills out few fields and then clicks on 'Clear Values' button in order to clear all the fields, then the fields don't get cleared. Insted of that the validations work and the error messages appear as per those validations.

I also tried the following code to clear all the fields:

```
 Response.Redirect("UserData.aspx");
```

(where 'UserData.aspx' is name of that webpage only). But, still it gives the same validation error messages.

How to tackle this?

Comment: You can clear with javascript or make the clear button not do validation. Or add a validation group to everything but clear button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me how do I go about clear button not letting do the validation? (I am new to ASP.Net and VB)

Comment: For that part of the answer -- see scartag's code. That's one easy way but also easy using JavaScript so you don't do postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button for "Clear Values"

You have to set its property `CausesValidation = "false"`

Answer (score 1):

After your user clicks the Submit or Clear button you can do something like this in a different method, and then call that method in your button's event handler:

```
public void ClearAll()
{
    textbox1.Text = "";
    textbox2.Text = "";
    textbox3.Text = "";

}
```

Make sure CausesValidation property is set to false for each of the buttons so that your validators aren't fired.